# R computes strange p value

Tags: r, t-test, p-value

I have two different t statistics which I want to use to compute corresponding p values. I don't understand why the second p value is what it is, when I compute it manually with `pt()`.

**First:**

`t = -1.30922`

Get p-value (two-sided):

`2 * pt(-1.30922, df = 208)`

Result:

`p = 0.1919042` (correct)

Check output of `t.test()` call:

```
t = -1.3092, df = 208, p-value =
0.1919
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 80
95 percent confidence interval:
 68.84975 82.25073
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 75.55024
```

**Second:**

`t = 1.424512`

Get p-value (two-sided):

`2 * pt(1.424512, df = 207)`

Result:

`p = 1.844196` (strange)

Check output of `cor.test()` call (because this time it's about Pearson-correlation):

```
t = 1.4245, df = 207, p-value = 0.1558
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.03768992  0.23115237
sample estimates:
       cor 
0.09852867
```

As you can see, the p-value should be `0.1558`.

When I use an online p-value calculator like e.g. [this one](https://www.socscistatistics.com/pvalues/tdistribution.aspx), I also get a p-value of `0.1558` when t is `1.4245`.

**Why do I get `p = 1.844196` when I calculate p manually?**

Comment: You forgot to negate the argument.

Comment: `2 * pt(1.424512, df = 207, lower.tail=FALSE)` .

Comment: @SalMangiafico: Ok, this works. But why do I have to pass that option to the second `pt()` call and not to the first one?

Comment: It's because the *t* value in the first example is negative.   If you look at the *t*-distribution, like in [https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/gif/tpdftb.gif](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/gif/tpdftb.gif).  You have to know whether you want the area to the left or the right of your *t* value.

Comment: set lower.tail=F and take the absolute value of your t-value to get a proper 2 sided test. Always visualize the distributional curve and the area you're calculating!

Comment: As stated, be sure to visualize the distributional curve, and be sure you're getting what you want.  A couple of options to get the small tail whether *t* is positive or negative:  `X = c(-1.4, 1.4);DF=200; 1-pt(abs(X), DF); pt(abs(X), DF, lower.tail=FALSE)`

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, you're getting the total probability of everything below a negative t-statistic, which represents the lower tail and can be doubled to get both tails.

In the second case, you're getting the total probability of everything below a positive t-statistic - this isn't the upper tail, it's *everything except* the upper tail. Doubling it does not represent both tails, it effectively counts both tails plus the middle of the distribution twice, which is why you get a nonsensical p-value above 1. The upper tail alone is represented by 1 minus the cumulative probability, that's the number to double to get the two-sided p-value.